# Saving Many-To-Many Field with self-reference in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, many-to-many

I am trying to save a many-to-many field with self reference through django-admin. This is my model:

```
class QuestionSetCategory(models.Model):
   parent_categories = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

When I save the relation with django-admin, it outputs the following error:

```
"<QuestionSetCategory: Test>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I think it is because, the category itself needs to be saved, before the reference to the field can exist. I read about overriding the save-method in my ModelForm, but I dont know, how to exactly do this.

I tried some solutions, but don't get the point.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Could you post your views.py?

Comment: i dont have one. I am just using django-admin.